# JQuery - Add Selected Elements Together - Combine Child Slectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to combine my Selector that selects an Element based on an mouseover Event. This is what I have so far.

```
parentItem.mouseenter(function ()
{
    var childItems = $(this).add(this + "li:first");
    childItems.show();
});
```

I understand that I can't use 'this' by itself nor can I add the two together, because it isn't a string.

How would I accomplish this concept? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `$(this).add($("li:first"));`?

Comment: Do you want to look for the childs of a fiven parent? Then use `$(this).find('li:first')` - http://api.jquery.com/find/.

Comment: @Rob W Yes that's it. I didn't realize that you could use that. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @dnxviral So which one is it? `$(this).add($("li:first"));` worked?

Comment: @Vega: You can just do `$(this).add("li:first");`, you don't need to wrap the selector inside `add` in `$`.

Comment: @Rocket mm true, but i think it is same :P http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.add

Comment: @Vega: Yeah, it's the same, but I think it looks cleaner without the second `$(`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to select the first `li` under the element that fired the event? You could use `this` as a *context*:

```
parentItem.mouseenter(function ()
{
    var childItems = $("li:first",this);
    childItems.show();
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. What parameters for the DOM? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `this + "li:first"`, `this` is a DOMElement, not a string.  Just do:

```
$(this).add("li:first");
```

Though, this may not be what you want.  This will find the first `<li>` on the page (and add it to a jQuery object containing `this`).

If you want the first `<li>` that's a child of `parentItem`, try this:

```
$("li:first", this);
```

(this is the same as `$(this).find("li:first");`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate `this` (in this case a DOM element) since it can't be coerced to a string.  `.add` simply adds more elements to the set.  `$(this)` already matches the current element (i.e. the one mouse over) so it seems that this would do what you need:

```
$(this).add("li:first").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to combine my Selector that selects an Element based on
>   an mouseover Event. This is what I have so far.

You do not specify what you want to achieve, netherless you could play around with next() prev() child() parent() jQuery methods

edit: Ayways is your goal just to simply select a first element of parents child?

Comment: I was establishing what I wanted to do, and what I had?

Comment: Well is your point to affect the first child of any element you select (then you would have to specify the global css selector like "*" or "body *" since it will sort of work as this for you initial selector)

Comment: @Malyo No I was getting the element that triggered the event then I wanted to get the child element of that element, Thanks though.